# nested dictionary find specific values from keys

Tags: python

How to get a value using keys in a nested dictionary in a specific context. Like as follows:

The nested dictionary is something like:

```
my_dict = { 'name': {0: 'alisa',1: 'monica',2: 'jessica'},
            'location': {0: 'america',1: 'canada',2: 'korea'},
            'age': {0: '22',1: '23',2: '24'}}
```

If the list is given with the values [0], [1], and [1], then the output has to be shown as 'alisa', 'canada' and '23'.

Comment: Do you mean `my_dict['name'][0]`, `my_dict['location'][1]`, and `my_dict['age'][1]`? This way, you can get the desired values by `'alisa'`, `'canada'`, and `'23'`. Remember to use the corresponding keys of the dictionary. Of course you can also loop through the keys, but it is not really 100 % clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Actually, I am working with the ML problem and the model predicted values as [0][1][1]. Using these values as keys how can I get results as mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure the given values are `[0][1][1]`? Not `[[0],[1],[1]]` or something similar?

Comment: YES The values are [0]
[1]
[1]

Comment: What does it show when you do `type([0][1][1])`? Because `[0][1][1]` is normally faulty. Maybe it has quotation marks and it is a string? Like `'[0][1][1]'`? I can provide you with an easy solution on your problem if you give me that information. Sorry for the effort, you will have to put in...

Comment: each one is shown for a specific like [0] is from the name, [1] is from the location and the last [1] is from the age.

Comment: for s_id, s_info in output_dictionary.items():
        print("\nSRS ID:", s_id)
        for key in s_info:
            if(key == model_predictions):
                print(key , ':', s_info[key])                        The problem with this code is that it can use these [0][1][1] and shows all the values of 'name' 'location' and 'age'. where as the modeil_prediction is a list which contains value [0][1][1]

Comment: Please edit your question when adding code as additional information. It is very difficult to read that in the comment (linebreaks are not available for example) and also the comment section is not for code snippets. ;)
See my answer below and look if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip the dictionary values and the list of keys to form the list:

```
my_dict = { 'name': {0: 'alisa',1: 'monica',2: 'jessica'},
            'location': {0: 'america',1: 'canada',2: 'korea'},
            'age': {0: '22',1: '23',2: '24'}}

keys   = [0,1,1]
result = [d[k] for d,k in zip(my_dict.values(),keys)]
# ['alisa', 'canada', '23']
```

*Note that [0][1][1] is not a valid Python data structure.  If you are receiving this as a string, you will need to convert it to a list of numbers (e.g. `keys = map(int,string[1:-1].split("]["))` )*

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your dictionary keys to achieve what you want. You can put your input values in a list in the order of your dictionary keys (first name, second location, and then age). The following code will generate the output in a list with the desired values.

```
my_dict = { 'name': {0: 'alisa',1: 'monica',2: 'jessica'},
            'location': {0: 'america',1: 'canada',2: 'korea'},
            'age': {0: '22',1: '23',2: '24'}}

name_index = [0]
location_index = [1]
age_index = [1]

given_values = [name_index,location_index,age_index]

def list_keys(dictionary, input_list):
    output_list = []
    for number, (key, value) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
        output_list.append(value[input_list[number][0]])
    return(output_list)


desired_values = list_keys(my_dict, given_values)

print(desired_values)
```